# Set Super to ignore keystroke when no shortcut exists

Tags: shortcut-keys

When I hold down Control and press a key that has no corresponding shortcut, nothing will happen onscreen (even if I'm in an input field). But if I hold down Super and do the same, the corresponding key will display in the input field. How can I set the Super modifier key to ignore the input for bad shortcuts rather than entering the key as if Super wasn't held in the first place?

Comment: It's actually a nice feature you might have not realized. Say you mispress the key. Instead of waiting for something to happen, you get instant feedback.

Comment: I think if that feedback were desirable, the other modifier keys would function the same way

Comment: Which desktop environment are you in? In Xubuntu, I don't see the key displayed in input field!

Comment: @Anwar Not sure about OP, but this occurs in Unity.

Comment: @wjandrea Now switched to Unity. but still no key is displayed!